# The entity passed to the `selectId` implementation returned undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-entity

i want to set token and refresh token in ngrx and save and use that for every request and when the page was reload not delete data in redux .

i implementation this state for this :

i dispatch data :

```
            this.getUserInformation().toPromise().then(responset => {
            if (response.success === true) {
                this.store.dispatch(new SetUserInformation({
                    displayName: responset['result']['displayName'],
                    userInfo: responset.result.claims,
                    RefreshTokenStatus:false,
                    accessToken:response['result']['access_token'],
                    refreshToken:response['result']['refresh_token']
                }))
            }
        });
```

in module i definde store :

```
    StoreModule.forFeature('Information', reducer),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([])
```

this is my reducer :

```
   const initialState = adapter.getInitialState({
    accessToken: null,
    refreshToken: null,
    RefreshTokenStatus: false,
    userInfo: null,
    displayName: null
})

export function reducer(state = initialState, action: TokenAction): TokenState {

    switch (action.type) {
        case TokenActionTypes.UserInformation:
            return adapter.addOne(action.payload, state)
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

and this is my model :

```
  export interface TokenState {
    accessToken: string;
    refreshToken: string;
    RefreshTokenStatus: boolean;
    userInfo: string[];
    displayName: string;
}
```

this is my `Selector`:

```
export interface State extends fromState.State, EntityState<TokenState> {
    UserInfo: TokenState;
}

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<TokenState> = createEntityAdapter<TokenState>();
const getTokenFetureState = createFeatureSelector<TokenState>('Information');


export const getAccessToken=createSelector(
    getTokenFetureState,
    state => state.accessToken
)
```

this is action :

```
   export class SetUserInformation implements Action {
    readonly type = TokenActionTypes.UserInformation;

    constructor(public payload: TokenState) {
    }
}

export type TokenAction = SetUserInformation
```

**now i have tow problem :**

```
 this.store.pipe(select(fromTokenSelect.getAccessToken)).subscribe(data=>{
     console.log(data)
 })
```

A: when i want to get token for use that it return null and show me this error :

> @ngrx/entity: The entity passed to the `selectId` implementation returned undefined. You should probably provide your own `selectId` implementation. The entity that was passed: Object The `selectId` implementation: (instance) => instance.id

B: when reload the page it delete data from ngrx.

**how can i solve this problem ?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `ngrx/entity` for non-entity data. Entity is designed to work with arrays of data, where each element has some kind of unique identifier. That is why it is throwing the error: you're feeding it non-entity-compatible data. You need to write a simple reducer which simply sets the state, not one which tries to add data to a non-existent entity.

As for page reload, NgRx will always reset the data, that is the expected behavior. You need to implement `localStorage` saving if you want to persist data over time.